# Creating contains function for a Bash array

Tags: bash, bash-functions

I have this contains function which is supposed to check if an array has a certain value. The array itself is passed as the 1st arg, and the value is the 2nd arg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;

branch_type="${1:-feature}";
arr=( 'feature', 'bugfix', 'release' );

contains() {
    local array="$1"
    local seeking="$2"
    echo "seeking => $seeking";
#    for v in "${!array}"; do
     for v in "${array[@]}"; do
        echo "v is $v";
        if [ "$v" == "$seeking" ]; then
         echo "v is seeking";
            return 0;
        fi
    done
   echo "returning with 1";
   return 1;
}

if ! contains "$arr" "$branch_type"; then
    echo "Branch type needs to be either 'feature', 'bugfix' or 'release'."
    echo "The branch type you passed was: $branch_type"
    exit 1;
fi

echo "all goode. branch type is $branch_type";
```

if you run the script without any args, it should work, since the default is "feature", but for some reason, the search is not matching anything. I am not getting an error, but the contains functions is not working as desired.

When I run the script w/o any arguments, I get:

```
seeking => feature
v is feature,
returning with 1
Branch type needs to be either 'feature', 'bugfix' or 'release'.
The branch type you passed was: feature
```

now that's weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** I'm going to show how to fix this so that it works in Bash 4.

---

I think you're passing the array into the function incorrectly:

```
$ cat contains.bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

branch_type="${1:-feature}";
arr=('feature' 'bugfix' 'release');

contains() {
    local array=$1
    local seeking="$2"
    for v in ${!array}; do
        if [ "$v" == "$seeking" ]; then
            return 0;
        fi
    done
   return 1;
}

if ! contains arr $branch_type; then
    echo "Branch type needs to be either 'feature', 'bugfix' or 'release'."
    echo "The branch type you passed was: $branch_type"
    exit 1;
fi

echo "the array contains: $branch_type";
```

I changed things slightly and it now looks to be working:

```
$ ./contains.bash
the array contains: feature
```

#### Changes

I only made 2 modifications to your original script. I changed how the function `contains()` was being called so that it passes the bare name of the array `arr` for this line:

```
if ! contains arr $branch_type; then
```

and changed this line inside the function `contains()` where the array is set using the passed in arguments, taking the quotes off the setting of the local variable `array`:

```
    local array=$1
```

#### References

- [How to pass an array as function argument?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674333/how-to-pass-an-array-as-function-argument)
- [Passing multiple distinct arrays to a shell function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953833/passing-multiple-distinct-arrays-to-a-shell-function)

Comment: @AlexanderMills - sure thing, good luck w/ the rest of it.

Comment: yeah I found something that works with bash3, I think this only works with bash4...i have to support bash3, also I don't understand why you can do `constains arr` instead of `contains "$arr"`

Comment: That's provided by Bash 4 now. The link I shared shows both 3 & 4 solutions.

Comment: got it yeah i added an answer with what seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Something idiomatic that works with Bash3, looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e; 

branch_type="${1:-feature}";
arr=( 'feature' 'bugfix' 'release' );

contains() {

    local seeking="$1"
    shift 1;
    local arr=( "$@" )

    for v in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [ "$v" == "$seeking" ]; then
            return 0;
        fi
    done
   return 1;
}

if ! contains "$branch_type" "${arr[@]}"; then
    echo "Branch type needs to be either 'feature', 'bugfix' or 'release'."
    echo "The branch type you passed was: $branch_type"
    exit 1;
fi

echo "the array contains: $branch_type";
```

the real hang up was I was trying to do this:

```
local seeking="$1"
local arr=( "$2" )
```

but this is necessary:

```
local seeking="$1"
shift 1;
local arr=( "$@" )
```

Comment: The `arr` array in the function is not needed:  `for v do if [ "$v" = "$seeking" ] ... done`.  This would loop over `"$@"`.

Comment: oh thanks, so to be precise would it be `for v; do`?

Comment: One out of `for v do`, `for v; do` or `for v in "$@"; do`.